# How can I change my username on Google Help Forums?

Tags: account-management, google, google-product-forums

When you attempt to create an account on [Google Help Forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum?hl=en), it asks for a username to use. Each username is unique.

I have an old account which I set up to use my desired username. Now when I try to use my new email account to create a Google Help account, I can't use that username since my old account is already using it.

How can I remove or change the username from the old account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it's a permanent setting<sup>[[A]](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=27e4f413ae6c16d7&hl=en)[[B]](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=0ac18d811e232ad5&hl=en&fid=0ac18d811e232ad50004807e15878310)[[C]](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=4a6e4365879415dc&hl=en)</sup>, there's no way to change your username. When you create a new account, you must choose a username that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

This must have changed as I was just able to change my user name on the Google Voice Help Forum. Here is what I did.

1. While in the forum (e.g. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/voice for Google Voice), click the settings icon and select "Membership and email settings". I think your display name may be specific to each Forum so you might have to do this for every forum you are a member, but I'm not sure.

[image]

2. In the pop-up, change the user name in the text box next to your profile picture

[image]

3. Click save
4. ???
5. Profit